# In this image where is the base of Q3 connected to?

Tags: operational-amplifier, diodes, bjt

In this image the base of Q3 shows an arrow that points to the 10k resistor, but I do not know where is it connected to.

Image:

[image]

According to that image I do not know what should I do with the base of Q3 and I have a problem.

I was implementing that circuit in Proteus like this :

[image]

Where should I connect the base of Q3?

Answer (score 3):

That 10K resistor is a potentiometer.  The base is connected to the middle pin.  The arrow represents the wiper.

Answer (score 0):

This is the schematic sumbol of a [variable resistor (potentiometer)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer). the 10k is its maximum value. So the potentiometer can go from ~0 Ohms to 10k Ohms.

[image: Potentiometer]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether proteus can implement a potentiometer directly. However this method will work for all simulators that can use expressions in the component value fields - see your specific simulator documentation for the correct expression syntax.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd4tm7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Alpha is a parameter between 0 and 1 that represents the setting of the potentiometer, 0 = fully left, 0.5 = centred, 1 = fully right.